# How to print very long string without wrapping in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Example:

```
print("Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
```

Outputs:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque 
ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto 
beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
```

Desired output:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
```

Comment: I see @Manikandan's and @ycx's answers but maybe I was not clear. It's not the wrapping on the code or markdown block that bothers me. It's the wrapping on the **output** of a code block. When you use a `print` command a new block just under the code block appears with the output. It's this block that I want without line wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Type in your cmd prompt or equivalent: `jupyter --config-dir` to get your jupyter settings location.
Create a folder `nbconfig` inside the settings location `/.jupyter`. Inside, create a file `notebook.json` with the following

```
{
  "MarkdownCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": false
    }
  },
  "CodeCell": {
    "cm_config": {
      "lineWrapping": false
    }
  }
}
```

Restart jupyter and reload, then try

Answer (score 0):

Directly go through this page
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/106

Answer (score 0):

You need HTML output that has some CSS applied. Here is the code that you may try:

```
import IPython.display as dp
long_txt = "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
outp = dp.HTML("<style>.nowrap{white-space:nowrap;}</style><span class='nowrap'>" +long_txt+ "</span>")
```

Now you get `outp` as an HTML object. You can render it and get the long one-line text.

```
outp
```

The `output` will be:

```
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
```

Hope it helps.